# rPi2 + Sandisk Ultra/Extreme plus/Extreme pro: would it work?

Tags: raspbian, storage

I'm thinking of using Sandisk Ultra/Extreme Plus/Extreme Pro with either 8GB or 16GB capacity.

I've searched the net about people having problem with Extreme/Ultra series but those are from older hardware/OS.

Will this microSD card work with an rPi 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sandisk Ultra/Extreme Plus/ Extreme Pro should work in the Raspberry Pi 2, recent kernel updates have fixed any previous problems associated with those cards. Have a look at the list on this website:

http://www.raspberry-pi.co.uk/2012/06/07/compatible-sd-cards/

And this page may also be useful to you:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=5057&start=175

Answer (score 2):

I personally use the [32GB Sandisk Ultra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00M55C0NS) in my RPi 2.  It works really well, and so long as you have a decent power supply, you shouldn't have any issues with most name brand microSD cards.

Comment: I've accumulated several 5v 2A phone chargers through the years from Samsung/Sony (chargers that came with the device). :) Thanks for the tip though!